# User ralated Data from other model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have 2 persons with same name in user model,and both of them have intrest too and level under Intrest model,How can i get a level of the person from User model in session model.
And how can i fetch that data in views.
class User(models.Model):

```
user_name=models.CharrField(max_length=30):
```

class Intrest(models.Model):

```
user=models.Foreignkey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
sports=models.CharrField(max_length=30)
line=(
    ('Beginner','Beginner'),
    ('Intermediate','Intermediate'),
    ('Advance','Advance'),
)

level=models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=line)
```

class Session(models.Model):

```
Person=models.Foreignkey(User)
Level=
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case one user can have many Intrests. Thats why If you want to get all you can do:

```
user = User.objects.get(...)
intrests = user.intrest_set.all()
levels = intrests.values_list('level', flat=True)
```

But in case you want to get the first one:

```
user = User.objects.get(...)
intrest = user.intrest_set.first()
levels = intrest.level if intrest else ''  # in case user doesn't have intrests.
```

Comment: a person will have many intrests in case he has many sports too,